# Use pyspark to read data from azure fileshare

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-file-share

Hey guys does anyone have an idea how I can read qvd data from azure fileshare

I want to read these qvd convert to parquet  then load the data using ADF to the container

But I am having  trouble using synapse to read data from specified fileshare this is how the path is defined

```
base_path = f'abfss://fileshare@storagename.file.core.windows.net'
adf_path= f'{base_path}/WMOS/WMOS'
```

i get

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature
```

however same code but for blob in the same container works

Answer (score 1):

First,  make sure you have python between these version [3.6 - 3.9]

While creating apache spark pool select spark version in such a way that python version should be between as mentioned above.

Next, create a notebook in your synapse workspace add following code.
To get data from **Azure file Share** , you need to download it locally and read into pandas then to spark dataframe.

Add below code blocks into you notebook.

```
pip install azure-storage-file-share==12.1.0 qvd
```

installs required package.

```
from qvd import qvd_reader
localpath="tmp.qvd"
connection_string = "Your_conn_string_to_storage_account"
share_name = "Your_file_share_name"
directory_name = "dir_name_in_fileshare"
file_name = "Airlines.qvd"

def  download_from_file_storage():
    share_client = ShareClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, share_name)
    file_client = share_client.get_file_client(directory_name + '/' + file_name)
    with  open(localpath, "wb") as  file:
        download_stream = file_client.download_file()
        file.write(download_stream.readall())
        
download_from_file_storage()
```

Function which downloads file into local file system.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = qvd_reader.read(localpath)
s_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
s_df = s_df.withColumn("AirlineId",col("%Airline ID")).drop(col("%Airline ID"))
display(s_df)
```

Here, reading qvd file from local and converting it to spark dataframe.

[image]

Next, using linked service writing that data to adls2 storage as **parquet**.

[image]

```
linkedServiceName_var = "adls2link"
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type", "com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedSASProvider")
spark.conf.set("spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName", linkedServiceName_var)

raw_container_name = "data"
raw_storageaccount_name = "jgsadls2"
relative_path = "qvd_parquet"
path = f"abfss://{raw_container_name}@{raw_storageaccount_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/qvd_parquet"
s_df.write.parquet(path)
```

Before, executing this you need to create linked service to your adls storage.

Output:

[image]

and

[image]

If you want to use this in pipeline, add this notebook to pipeline with exit value as **path** and run it.
Then take the path in output of the pipeline and use it further.

[image]